# Align or don't align char arrays on stack?

Tags: c, arrays, char, memory-alignment

I have the following code:

```
char stats[109]; /* !LINE UNDER QUESTION! */
sprintf(stats,
    "OBJECTS:\n%u/256\n" \
    "BLOCKS:\n%u/" GP_ConstantExpand(Map_MaxLightmaps) "\n" \
    "QUADS:\n%u/" GP_ConstantExpand(Map_MaxLightmaps) "\n" \
    "LIGHTMAPS:\n%u/" GP_ConstantExpand(Map_MaxLightmaps) "\n" \
    "CHECKPOINTS:\n%u/256\n" \
    "HINTS:\n%u/256",
    Map_This_Header.objects, Map_This_Header.blocks, Map_This_QuadCount,
    lmapcount, Map_This_Header.checkpoints, Map_This_Header.hints);
```

Is it fine to statically allocate array of 109 chars (109 is enough for my text), or aligning the array to 128 bytes will increase performance?

I don't care about file size and memory use, performance is important for me, my code must run at 60 FPS on old computers.

Comment: Since performance is critical for you.The only way to go about this is to test both the approaches and profile them on your environment.That will give you more accurate assessment than wise guesses that you will get here.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, why are you doing a load of text formatting?

Comment: Also, not caring about memory use may also harm performance if you start getting cache misses because you have too much data to fit into cache space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is too much related on the hardware on which the code will run. We can think for instance of two opposite arguments to answer this, assuming there will be other variables allocated on the stack around your array:

- if you keep the array small, it will reduce the number of cache entries used to hold all the variables frequently used.
- if you align the size on a power of two, and the address of the array is in one register of the CPU, calculating the address of the variable just after can be easier depending on the addressing mode of the CPU. For instance, it is easier for the ARM to encode an offset like 0x12000 than 0x12001, because it is taking a bitfield and shifting it.

The second argument seems however less relevant, as it will only impact one variable among the many you can instantiate. In any case, you will need to benchmark your code if you want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

If aligning it would increase performance, the compiler should align it for you at the appropriate optimization level. This is because the compiler is free to order and align automatic variables as it sees fit.

In general, unless your code actually *requires* it to be aligned to operate (for instance if you're storing an integer in the low bits of pointer fields and thereby need the actual base pointer to be aligned to a larger boundary), you should not be coding assumptions like this into your code.